# How to get the database snapshot of a Hibernate Managed Entity just before it is flushed

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, flush

I wonder if Hibernate could retrieve the original field value of an Entity before updating it?

For example, having the entity

```
class StkItem {
     private int Qty;
}
```

After the user enters a new quantity, could I know what is the database value of Qty before saving the new value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure a custom [Hibernate Interceptor](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/EmptyInterceptor.html) and overwrite the [onFlushDirty](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/EmptyInterceptor.html#onFlushDirty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.io.Serializable,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.String[],%20org.hibernate.type.Type[]%29) method, which contains batch the old state and the new one:

- Object entity,
- Serializable id,
- Object[] currentState,
- Object[] previousState,
- String[] propertyNames,
- Type[] types